# Apache mod_rewrite static resource

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My ".htaccess" file is here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* route.php [L]
```

That is for the RestURI.
And I want to define RewriteRule for my static resources
The rule is here.

1. URI pattern is "^.*/static/.+$" (Request : http://domain/root/static/css/style.css)
2. Response resource from this location if pattern has matched (Location : /static/css/style.css)

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If i underdtood right:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(/static/.*)$ $1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I solved as set this `RewriteRule ^(?:.*/)*static/(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]`

Comment: what is the difference?